# No puedo guardar un registro por el tipo de dato char en c# MVC

Tags: c#, mvc

Tengo una tabla productos y el código lo tengo como `char(6)` en la capa de dato y negocio hago todo el proceso, ahora en la capa presentación convierto el `string` en char usando `Convert.TChar(txtcodigo.Text)`, no me manda ni un error hasta guardar el registro me dice

> "Error la cadena debe tener exactamente un caracter".

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrarnos el codigo? porque tendrias algo como char, si ocupa mas de un caracter???

Comment: Lo que estás intentando es tratar de convertir muchos caracteres en uno sólo, se supone que se insertaría sin problemas sin que hagas esa conversión